# Creating C DLL and using it in Golang?

Tags: c, windows, go, dll, g++

I want to create DLL in C and use it in Golang.

I used [this tutorial](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll) to generate dll :
helloWorld.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
void __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) hello();
```

helloWorld.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "helloWorld.h"
__stdcall void hello()
{
    printf("Hello World !!");
}
```

I used this in command Prompt to compile it

```
g++ -c helloWorld.c
g++ -shared -o helloWorld.dll helloWorld.o -Wl,--out-implib,libhelloWorld.a
```

I was able to use the generated dll in this C code , named as example.c :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "helloWorld.h"
int main()
{
    hello();
}
```

and compile it using

```
g++ -c example.c
g++ -o example.exe example.o -L. -lhelloWorld
```

But while using the DLL in Golang , i am getting error , please help me

test.go

```
package main 

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -lhelloWorld
#include "helloWorld.h"
*/
import "C"

func main(){

    C.hello()
}
```

Error :

```
# command-line-arguments
C:\Users\kumarmoh\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build544493490\b001\_x002.o: In function `_cgo_525f579e070a_Cfunc_hello':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:40: undefined reference to `hello'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z04QC.png)

Other info :

1. go version go1.11 windows/amd64
2. 64-bit OS , x64-based processor , Windows 10
3. I tried creating dll in Visual studios and it gave me error as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886645/mingw-w64-linker-skipping-incompatible-files-when-searching-for-third-party-stat) .

Comment: The problem may comes from the dll compiled for 32 bits system, while the go program is for 64 bits? Try adding `-m64` in `g++` invocation

Comment: Please do not post image that contains text, instead, quote it in your question.

Comment: @purplepsycho. Thank you for your reply , i compiled using " g++ -m64 -shared -o helloWorld.dll helloWorld.o -Wl,--out-implib,libhelloWorld.a" , it still gave me same error .

Comment: @Afshin , example.c was able to consume helloWorld.dll , but still , i tried compiling helloWorld.c with gcc after reading your comment. Thank you so much . it worked.