# Mingw-w64-g++ cross compilation error incompatible libraries

Tags: g++, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I am trying to cross compile using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` with the `-m32` option for 32bit windows. I am using the standard library only, nothing extra.

I am getting this output::

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -m32 *.cpp -o ../build/rook-win-x86.exe -O3 -Wall 
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lmingw32
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lmoldname
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lmingwex
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lmsvcrt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems the libraries are incompatible.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886645/mingw-w64-linker-skipping-incompatible-files-when-searching-for-third-party-stat) question which was about this issue. But the answer there was to use Microsoft's `link.exe` and I want to do it on linux only.

I tried installing `gcc-multilib` and `g++-multilib`. However that did not resolve it.

Comment: Is there no `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` compiler available that you can use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-m32` and `-m64` are to tell `gcc`/`g++` which Windows you are targeting, especially when using native MinGW-w64 on Windows.

On Linux cross platform building usually involved prepending the compiler tools with the platform's triplet.

So in case of `g++` use `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` to target Windows 32-bit and `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` to target Windows 64-bit.