# opengl32.a is incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, opengl, g++, mingw

I am learning to use the Opengl library, and my work is on vscode.

Link errors persist during compilation and runtime:

```
d:/g++/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:/g++/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can confirm that my source file can retrieve the opengl32.a file.I doubt if the architecture of the compiler is different from the architecture required by Opengl32.

Can someone help me?

Below is the compiler information I am using:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=D:\G++\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=d:/g++/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-multilib --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --with-sysroot=/c/temp/gcc/dest --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-verbose --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-win32-registry --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --with-zstd=/c/mingw --disable-bootstrap
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (GCC)
```

Answer (score 0):

The library might be compiled for 32 bit.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886645/mingw-w64-linker-skipping-incompatible-files-when-searching-for-third-party-stat) has some useful information, e.g., try running `objdump.exe -x` on the library file to get more information about it.